# Pagination in ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've recently started learning ruby-on-rails and now I've got to the point where I can create something but still not very comfortable with syntax.

Today I've been working on pagination, so as you can see I want to display 15 items per page, so this is working great for now:

```
<% (0..@items_count).step(15) do |i| %>
     <li class="<%='active' if params[:offset].to_i == i%>"><%= link_to i/15+1, items_path(:offset => i) %></li>
<% end %>
```

Here is the part where I'm stuck :

```
<% (0..@items_count).step(15) do |i| %>
     <li class="<%='active' if params[:offset].to_i == i%>"><%= link_to i/15+1, items_path(:offset => i, :age => 10) %></li>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to pass some additional params beside offset but not able to do it because of the language skill limitation (from my side)

So currently my link looks like this :

```
http://localhost:3000/items?offset=20
```

But my point is to have links with multiple params like this :

```
http://localhost:3000/items?offset=20&age=10
```

But not just one but n params

**Solution :**

thanks to MrYoshiji for providing the answer.
I was trying to do it directly with `:age => "params[:age]"`

But this worked :

```
:age=> "#{params[:age]}"
```

Logic applied to the example above :

```
<% (0..@items_count).step(15) do |i| %>
         <li class="<%='active' if params[:offset].to_i == i%>"><%= link_to i/15+1, items_path(:offset => i, :age => "#{params[:age]}") %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you tried out the will_paginate gem yet?

Comment: I have no issue with pagination, did you read the question? pagination is working perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass more attributes in the path helpers:

```
items_path(:offset => i, :age => 10) 
# should generates an url with get params like following: 
/items?offset=12&age=10 # (assuming 'i' = 12)
```

From the documentation [seen on **APIdock.com #link_to**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to):

```
link_to "Nonsense search", searches_path(:foo => "bar", :baz => "quux")
# => <a href="/searches?foo=bar&baz=quux">Nonsense search</a>
```